# Customizing twig form template for inputs inside containers in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a FormType that have this datetime input:

```
    $builder->add('data_inicio', 'datetime', array(
        'input' => 'datetime',
        'date_widget' => 'single_text',
        'time_widget' => 'choice',
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'datetime rangeDataInicio',
            'maxlength' => '10',
            'placeholder' => 'dd/mm/aaaa',
        ),
        'date_format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
        'required' => true,
        'disabled' => $isDisabled,
    ));
```

Form some reasons, I have to insert the placeholder and the class direct at the single_text date input, but both of them stays at the container and don't go to the input.

I tried a several ways to do this and all of them failed and searched the web for a couple of weeks and found nothing that could sove my problem. How can I put these two attrs at the input?

Comment: Why not use jquery datetime picker instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [form theme](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#referencing-base-form-blocks-twig-specific) for this.

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block datetime_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if widget == 'single_text' %}
        {{ block('field_widget') }}
    {% else %}
        <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
            {{ form_errors(form.date) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.time) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.date) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.time, { 'attr': {'class': 'datetime rangeDataInicio', 'placeholder': 'dd/mm/aaaa'} })) }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock datetime_widget %}
```